# java ee 7 : using interceptors for centralized logging

Tags: interceptor, java-ee-7

I'd like to have one class responsible for my logging. The way I understand it,  that's what interceptors can be used for. Here's my interceptor:

```
package logging;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

public class LoggingInterceptor implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2095670799863528243L;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("before calling method :"
                + context.getMethod().getName());

        Object[] params = context.getParameters();
        for (Object param : params) {
            System.out.println("PARAM " + param.toString());
        }

        Object result = context.proceed();


        System.out.println("after calling method :"
                + context.getMethod().getName());

        return result;

    }
}
```

I annotated various methods with the `@Interceptor` annotation.

My question is: How do I differentiate between the methods that are called? Depending on the method, I want to log a different message and maybe some parameters like folder names.

Right now, the only thing I can think of is a big `if-elseif-else` or `switch` statement to check the name of the method.

But this seems to be poor design. Am I using the interceptor for the right purpose? And if so, how would I go about implementing logging in a clean way?

I'd like to have one class responsible for logging because I want to display methods on the user interface as well as log to a file. Also, I'd like to use some java ee 7 built-in java ee 7 mechanism for such a cross-cutting concern.

Comment: Logging is a very common scenario for interceptors. But keep in mind, that you should keep the code within very generic, it should not know of and do individual things with certain methods.

Comment: hmhm... so a logging class that I inject into other classes would be more appropriate here? Or what would be a good solution?

Comment: If it's just about logging, then yes, you'd inject a logger everywhere you need it. But in your case you want to have a cross-cutting concern on one place, for which it is appropriate to use an interceptor. Only thing to keep in mind is, that this class has to be generic and must not have dependencies on the code which it intercepts. This can for example be used in a REST-Service to log all requests - but again, you should work on the information you have in a generic way.

Comment: right, okay, thanks for the tip!